# Replace first occurrence from the end of a string in R

Tags: r, string, character

As an example I have this vector

```
c("qw;erty;qwert;qwe;", "ty;qwert;qw")
```

How can I use `sub` function or any other to replace first occurrences of ";" from the end of the line with "\t" so the result will be `c("qw;erty;qwert;qwe\t", "ty;qwert\tqw")` ?

Comment: Try `sub(";([^;]*)$","\t\\1",c("qw;erty;qwert;qwe;", "ty;qwert;qw"))`

Comment: @nicola I didn't see your comment but it is surprisingly similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try

```
sub(";([^;]*)$", "\t\\1", str1)
#[1] "qw;erty;qwert;qwe\t" "ty;qwert\tqw"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("qw;erty;qwert;qwe;", "ty;qwert;qw")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `stri_replace_last_regex` from `stringi` package.

```
stringi::stri_replace_last_regex(str1, ";", "\t")
```